# Video streaming from a Camera over the internet

Tags: iphone

I want to write an application which streams a video content which is obtained from a camera (IP Camera) over the internet. By reading some of the posts I have a doubt that only the built-in camera of iPhone can be video streamed. Can I access any other camera and capture images from it?

Precisely can I access other cameras on iPhone and display live video?

Answer (score 0):

> "By reading some of the posts I have a doubt that only the built-in camera of iPhone 
>   can be video streamed. Can I access any other camera and capture images from it?"

From this I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Are you asking if you can capture images from other cameras on your iPhone? Or are you asking if you can stream live video from your iPhone?

So without truly understanding your request, here is the best response I can come up with:

- The iPhone can stream, and [there are services available for this](http://qik.com/video/100699).
- The iPhone can be accessed programmatically [it appears](http://code.google.com/p/iflickr/source/browse/trunk/bkp/PhotoLibrary.h?r=10).

Comment: The iPhone can't stream video by default (yet?). You have to do your own decoding.

Answer (score -1):

check out ustream.tv app for iPhone. I dont think its available in the app store, but in the cydia store - This involves jailbreaking of ur iPhone